# What non-dairy filler to use in white chocolate style coatings?

Tags: substitutions, cake, chocolate, glaze

Recipes for white chocolate style cake (or ice cream/truffle/...) coatings (the snappy kind, not soft frostings) tend to rely on cocoa butter, shortening, sugar... and milk powder as a filler. Soymilk powders are not available everywhere and make an unreliable substitute due to very brand dependent additives and properties. What can be used as a reliable, non-dairy filler?

Comment: ?? Cocoa butter is not dairy. Coconut oil is often used in vegan chocolate, but I am unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Not asking for a substitute to the cocoa butter, but the solids that bulk it out - even a white chocolate bar, vegan or not, is not just cocoa butter either since it would be very translucent and very expensive :)

Comment: And for this function, milk powder is usually suggested in recipes.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I would look at almond flour.

what milk powder gives to the recipe is proteins, sugars, and fats - all of which are present in nuts.  This is also why almond milk is totally a thing, there are a lot of similarities.

Two major differences are, there will be an almond flavor instead of a (milder, more "neutral") milky flavor.  And, almond milk has some of the almond solids removed, using almond flour is therefore "grittier" (not quite sure how else to put it) that using milk powder.  A true substitute would be extracting and dehydrating almondmilk, so those extra solids aren't present.  But, honestly that's a lot of work, and almond flour will probably work well enough - though you might revisit if you're using a lot, or if you think it's worth the extra work.

Of course, any other nut flours will also work, and even soy flour or coconut flour (both of whose precedents can be made into -milk) can be adapted.  The extra flavors will be in the finished product, but they can be left as subtle, or celebrated, or something.

Comment: Good Idea :) Almond milk is readily commercially available here, how to dry it without a lot of loss will be another interesting headache (wide pans in an oven and a lot of scraping?) :)

Comment: @rackandboneman - actually, on further reflection... is non-dairy creamer not a thing you can use, or does it have some other problematic ingredient?  I'm sure I've seen it on store shelves, and it seems like a tailor-made substitute for milk powder - especially if you use the dry or powdered stuff - since it outright claims its non-dairy status.  But then again, there might be some other problem with using it I'm not aware of.

Comment: non-dairy creamer is not common in every country :) Outcome might be very, very brand dependent. Commonly sold "soy drink powder" tends to give a clumped/gritty result.

Comment: @rackandboneman - This is true.  I still would have felt less silly if I'd remembered it in time to add it to my answer as one more possible option, instead of hours later as a comment.